# Problem exporting with pdflatex

Tags: errors, pdftex, lyx

I'm having a funny problem with exporting to pdf, working with LyX.
On certain paths it's working fine, but for files saved in specific folders
I'm having the `"missing \begin{document}"` error.
 There is an output
that shows the wanted text with `gibberish` in the beginning.

this is a link to the log of a minimal example:
https://pastebin.com/rPwEJAh2

Does anyone know what might be the case here?
Thanks.

Comment: unless you show the start of the generated latex document  and teh exact error that tex generates there is not really any help anyone can give as there is no information here.

Comment: Paths with spaces?

Comment: Please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: you can view the log here: 
https://pastebin.com/rPwEJAh2